# SQL XML: Replace root node

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have many XML documents that each have a root node named `<DocumentXML>`. I want to delete the root node and replace it with `<DocumentXML xmlns=""><Comment>Anonymised</Comment></DocumentXML>`

for all the documents. How do I best solve this with SQL? I've come this far:

```
DECLARE @anoDoc xml
SET @anoDoc = '<DocumentXML xmlns=""><Comment>Anonymised</Comment></DocumentXML>'
UPDATE [myTable]
SET [Input].modify('delete(/DocumentXML)')
SET [Input].modify('insert sql:variable("@anoDoc") into (/
```

Comment: Why not UPDATE [myTable] SET [Input]=@anoDoc

Comment: Try it ;-) - it does replace the XML with the anonymized one. If needed add a where clause to only anonymize some of the rows.

Comment: @Lucero So this will do the trick?

`UPDATE [ApplicationScoreLog]
SET [Input].modify('delete(/DocumentXML)')`

`DECLARE @anoDoc xml
SET @anoDoc = '<DocumentXML xmlns=""><Comment>Anonymised</Comment></DocumentXML>'
UPDATE [ApplicationScoreLog]
SET [Input] = @anoDoc`

Comment: no need to first delete as the code replaces the XML anyways

Comment: Why do you want an empty default namespace? What should happen with the existing document? Please add sample data!

Comment: @Shnugo I just do what the developers ask :)

Comment: @Simon, OK... Please add sample data with expected output.